# Strange visibility issue with CSS menu in IE7

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a CSS-only menu (ie. no JS) that works great in all modern browsers, but has a weird bug in IE7. It doesn't work well at all in IE6, but we don't need to address that here. The issue is as follows:

When you mouse over a menu option tab, the dropdown appears. When you mouse off that option, the dropdown disappears - and in IE7 only, the tab also disappears! The bit that gets me is this - the tab will reappear if you mouse over it again, or if you mouse over ANY OTHER TAB. How is this even possible?! A mouseover on another element making the original tab visible agin?? The annoying thing is, it worked in the last incarnation of this website, and somehow in the new design, it's gotten broken. I've tried comparing and can't work out what it is.

Here's a fiddle of the current broken version: http://jsfiddle.net/pXZLJ/1/

Here's one of the old working one: http://jsfiddle.net/43utK/

View these in IE7 to see the problem. Help? Thanks :)

Comment: FYI it is working on IE9, better to ask without minified css

Comment: Yep, it works in IE8 too. The issue only seems to be with IE7. Sorry about the minification, I prefer to work with CSS this way, so all my CSS is in this format.

Comment: @zenkaty, Can you change the styles or do you want to keep them the as they are but make them work in IE7 as well? I have made a few changes to the styles, mainly simplified them, that work in IE7, FF and Chrome. These styles should work in IE6/7/8/9 (here's hoping. Since I don't have IE8/9 I can't test them in there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting this line in your css: `.nrmenu * {position:relative}`. It seems to fix things.

EDIT: As sarcastyx pointed out, it does seem to affect the dropdown menus. So, add `position:relative` to `.nrmenu li` and dropdown menu appears again.

Comment: One interesting thing happens when you remove the `position: relative;`. None of the sub menu links display any more.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It's weird, I swear that was the first thing I tried - maybe I was cached when I tried to refresh and thought it didn't work. Thanks :)